# Vscode devcontainer - how to dynamically specify build args based on local machine (ie M1 mac)

Tags: vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I'm developing with vscode devcontainers and its working great so far. I use the following to start my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-18
```

However when a colleagues wants to help it fails as he has a new arm64 based mac.
I believe for amr 64 we need to do it like this:

```
# [Choice] Node.js version (use -bullseye variants on local arm64/Apple Silicon): 18, 16, 14, 18-bullseye, 16-bullseye, 14-bullseye, 18-buster, 16-buster, 14-buster
ARG VARIANT=16-bullseye
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:${VARIANT}
```

Which is all good and fine but we want it to work for all devs regardless of their local machine type.

I know we can also pass in an ARG to docker via the vscode devcontainer config like this:

```
    "build": {
      "dockerfile": blah blah,
      "args": { blah }
    }
```

But this is not dynamic. I should be able to simply clone a repo and the developer can open vscode which builds the container and you are away...

Any ideas if this is possible?